# Prove that a certain ideal $I$ of $\mathbb Z [x]$ is not a principal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, ideals

It is a homework question which wants us to prove that  $I=(x,2)=\{h(x)=xf(x)+2g(x):f,g\in\mathbb Z[x]\}$ is not a principal ideal.

I thought of trying to make a contradiction but I have no idea where to start with.

Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Hint: Suppose it were principle. Then there would be $m(x), n(x), o(x) \in {\mathbb  Z}[x]$ such that $m(x)n(x)=x$ and $n(x)o(x) =2$. Look at what $n(x)$ has to look like; its constant term may be particularly englightening.

Comment: Start by assume it is principal generated by $a(x)$, say, so $x=b(x)a(x)$ and $2=c(x)a(x)$ for some polynomials $b$ and $c$.  Now look at degrees.

Comment: @JoshuaZ Thanks!

Comment: @Dzoooks Thanks!